# Image gets really small when I put it in a column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My png images gets really small when I put them inside a column in a row. However they are fine when there is not column but then they do not appear as a row and appear one above the other. I have no idea what may be causing the problem.

What I want to do: I want them to appear like this.

[image: SS]

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="row" id="parent">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 block left">
                        <div class="heading">
                            <h3> Simple to Enjoy </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inside">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class=""> <!--These Images!!!-->
                                    <img class="img img-responsive img-sec-4" src="images\home_section_4_free_ride.png">
                                    <p>Free Rides </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="">
                                    <img class="img img-responsive img-sec-4" src="images\home_section_4_membership.png">
                                    <p>Free XXX Membership </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 block center">
                        <div class="heading">
                            <h3> Simple to Earn </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inside">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 block right">
                        <div class="heading">
                            <h3> Simple to Save </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inside">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Sorry for bad english and indent.

Here is my CSS:

```
#parent {
        text-align:center;
        height:400px;
        width:100%;
    }
.center {
margin:auto
}
.left {
margin:auto auto auto 0;
}
.right {
margin:auto 0 auto auto;
}

.img-sec-4 {
height: auto;
width: auto;
}
```

EDIT:
Here is the screenshot of my result:
(The red highlighted area is where the problem is)

[image: SS]

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of the current result ?

Comment: Remove height:auto and width:auto from your css

Comment: what column size you add? can u try with col-xs-12?

Comment: It does not look like this https://jsfiddle.net/g5nyyk9n/ ? Because it probably should look like this with Bootstrap.

Comment: @Weedoze Thanks for your comment! I have made an edit

Comment: @Stages I have tried it, that doesn't solve it

Comment: I don't understand then. What is really the matter now and what do you want to achieve? be a little more precise pls

Comment: @Stages I have made an edit of what I want to do, there is a picture of what i want it to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply add class `col-xs-6` to the div wrapping those images (each one)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="parent">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 block left">
      <div class="heading">
        <h3> Simple to Enjoy </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="inside">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <!--These Images!!!-->
            <img class="img img-responsive img-sec-4" src="//lorempixel.com/200/200">
            <p>Free Rides</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <img class="img img-responsive img-sec-4" src="//lorempixel.com/200/200">
            <p>Free XXX Membership</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 block center">
      <div class="heading">
        <h3> Simple to Earn </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="inside">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 block right">
      <div class="heading">
        <h3> Simple to Save </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="inside">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```